# Does SDHC wear leveling take place if the same file is written repeatedly?

Tags: sdhc, physical-wear

We store a counter in a file on SDHC. The counter consists of 12 bytes. The counter value is updated periodically by code like

```
int fd = open( m_path, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, 0 );
write( fd, (char*)m_count, (1 + m_maxId) * sizeof( ULONG ) );
close( fd );
```

My question: assuming the SDHC supports internal wear-leveling, would it be applied in this case? Or would I need to actually delete the file and open a new file for that to happen?

I'm worried that since the same file is being reused, perhaps the same physical locations are being written to over and over.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm worried that since the same file is being reused, perhaps the same physical locations are being written to over and over.

Well, that is exactly the whole point of wear-leveling.

Upon reaching the memory card, all operations go through a "Flash Translation Layer" which makes its own decisions on where the data should go; its job is to translate between logical block addresses (issued by the OS) and physical locations (on flash memory).

And that's where wear-leveling happens – the FTL ensures that even though the OS is requesting writes to the same logical blocks, they're getting mapped to different physical locations.

Comment: But isn't that for determining the location of a *new* write? If an *existing* part of a file is overwritten, then the FTL would not only have to write the newly-mapped location for the data but then also mark the previous location as unused, right? I was under the impression that wear-leveling was to decide which location from the "pool" of physical locations to use for the next new write, and that the goal was to spread it out instead of using the same location over and over for a new allocation.

Comment: @MPW - Devices only accept `write` commands.  There is no such thing as a *"new write"*.  Every write command is handled by the device in the same way.  The FTL always looks for an already-erased block to perform the write, rather than reuse the current block (the absolute last choice).

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other answer: flash memory works kind of differently... it does not truly allow random writes.

NAND flash only allows a bit to be flipped from 1 to 0. To flip it the other way around (from 0 to 1) you need to erase a whole *page* - a part of NAND which is usually 4 kiB or larger (I've seen 128 kiB pages in a microcontroller's internal NAND).

The naive thing to do would be to load the whole page into RAM, change the bits you want to change, erase the page and then write again. Apart from increased wear this also runs the risk of losing data if you lose power during the process (unlikely but it does happen).

While we do not (and likely will not) know how exactly internal wear-levelling works in commercial eMMC or SD memories, we can look at how it is implemented in software, for devices which use unmanaged NAND (common in industrial computers, some routers and similar devices).

In general, the simplified algorithm for this is:

- read your file and some surrounding data (since your file is tiny) to RAM
- modify the data in RAM
- write the modified data in an empty location in the flash
- mark the old location as dirty

If every location in a page is marked as dirty then it can be safely erased. This is done in a separate process, aptly called *garbage collection*.

If you want to read up on this, one filesystem which implements this is [YAFFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAFFS), which is a [log-structured filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-structured_file_system).

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the additional information